# typing object property value wih Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am exporting a class in myInterfaces.ts

```
export class SettingsObj{
  lang : string;
  size : number;
}
```

Now I want to use this class in another file called myConfig.ts to type a propertyvalue of an object called CONFIG.

**myConfig.ts**

```
import { SettingsObj, ...};
...

    export var CONFIG = {
      // default settings
      settings : {
        lang : "eng",
        size : 10
      },...
    ...
    }
```

I can't type the properyvalue like

```
export var CONFIG = {
  // default settings
  setings : {...} : SettingsObj;
}
```

Is there a syntax or command for that ?

Comment: are you exposing your config via any service?

Comment: Iam loading my config into a  variable called data , this variable is indeed a Property of m Service class

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two solutions for this problem.

1 - Use constructor

```
export class SettingsObj{
  lang : string;
  size : number;

  constructor() {
    this.lang = "default size;
    this.size = 0 //replace with desired default
  }
}
```

2 - Expose default values via SettingsService

```
import { SettingsService } from 'path/to/service'

export class SettingsObj{
  lang : string;
  size : number;

  constructor(private settingsService: SettingsService) {
    this.lang = this.settingsService.defaultLang;
    this.size = this.settingsService.defaultSize;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a good Suggestion, but sadly I need to type the objects property directly ( any kind if Syntax I dont know of typescript to implement this ). I'm also ok with a Solution, where I dont have to use a class as object container. I can directly export a object if that is possible

Comment: You'll have to set them at some point. I don't think i understand clearly what you have in mind.

Comment: My CONFIG variable is just a var that will be used in a service called config.service.ts, and I just want to type some properties of this CONFIG var, so I dont forgett to init All necessary properties

Comment: I want to know if it is possible to type a objects propertyvalue (In my case the property called settings of my CONFIG var). I want to type it with my SetringsObj